# If for reversible process, ΔS= 0 for universe (system+surroundings), why would there be non-zero change in gibbs energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

As Second Law says, the entropy must increase for universe

$$\Delta S_\textrm{universe}\ge 0$$

Now, we know, $$\Delta G= -T\Delta S_\textrm{universe}\le 0^\dagger$$

For reversible process, $$\Delta S_\textrm{reversible, universe} = 0$$

That would mean $$\Delta G_\textrm{reversible}= 0$$

But does it happen so?

Peter Atkins, in his book writes:

> At constant temperature and pressure, for a **reversible process**: $\mathrm dG = \mathrm dw'_\rm{rev}\;.$

Now, isn't it contradicting that $\mathrm dG\ne 0$ for reversible process? If $\Delta G= -T\Delta S_\textrm{universe}$, then wouldn't $\mathrm dG= 0$ for $\mathrm dS_\textrm{universe}= 0$ during reversible process?

---

\begin{align}^\dagger \Delta S_\textrm{universe}&=\Delta S_\textrm{system}+ \Delta S_\textrm{surroundings} \\ &= \Delta S_\text{system}+ \frac{-\Delta H_\text{system}}{T} \\ \implies   -T\Delta S_\text{universe} &= \Delta H_\text{system} - T\Delta S_\text{system} \\&=\Delta G  \end{align}

Comment: Forgot about enthalpy H?

Comment: @Mithoron: Huh?

Comment: G=H-TS so your equations look wrong...

Comment: @Mithoron: Edited.

Comment: Think more about it and you'll see why you're wrong.

Comment: @Mithoron: Periodic Table?

Answer (score 3):

The equation in Atkins' book refers to the system only, and not to the universe, and, moreover, in this equation, w' specifically refers to non-PV work, like electrical.

Comment: G at constant temperature and pressure doesn't talk about the entropy of the universe?

Comment: I thought dG would be zero as $\mathrm dG= -T\mathrm dS_\rm{universe}$ and $\mathrm dS_\textrm{universe}= 0$ for reversible process?

Comment: Doesn't Atkins' book specify these constraints when it talks about the change in G for a system experiencing a process at constant temperature and pressure?  What exactly does the book say leading up to your highlighted statement?  How exactly does it define w' (with the prime)?  You seem to have omitted important details in your question.

Comment: He actually doesn't elaborate anything; only he does mention the term _maximum non-expansion work at const. temp. and pressure_

Comment: I guess he should have been more precise.  I don't have a copy of Atkins, but I can tell you the Denbigh (Principles of Chemical Equilibrium) has a development that spells this out with more precision.

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BV6cAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=non+expansion+work+gibbs+free+energy+peter+atkins+physical&source=bl&ots=N4rC6dkgPO&sig=kUlgR5ig24YI3D8V4-dbYtqBfd8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs5_GA047LAhUQC44KHQfVBuUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Two Thermodynamics books I highly recommend are Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al, and Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and Van Ness.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation; but I can't immediately buy either of the two now ;/

Comment: Don't you think Gibbs energy is related to non-expansion work?

Comment: In the online version you provided, the Justification 3.3 is similar to the development in Denbigh, although Denbigh is more precise. I do think that, for a reversible change at constant temperature and pressure, the change in the Gibbs energy is equal to the non-expansion work.

Comment: Oh! But reversible process means the change in entropy of the universe is 0, isn't it?

Comment: So?  What is your point?

Comment: As $\Delta S_\rm{universe}= 0$, the equation (valid at const. temp and pressure) $\Delta G= -T\Delta S_\textrm{universe}$ yields 0  but also the derivation that Atkins shows gives $\Delta G= w'$ anon-zero quantity. So, isn't it contradictory?

Comment: It's not contradictory.  The equation we have been discussing applies to a specific closed system, and not necessarily to the universe.  If you want to apply the equation to the universe, then, for the universe, w' = 0, because the universe is not doing any reversible non-PV work on anything.  The reversible non-PV work that a closed system does on the surroundings is exactly equal in magnitude and opposite in sign to the reversible non-PV work that the surroundings does on the system.  So, if you include both system and surroundings, the reversible non-PV work is zero.

Comment: Are you saying $\Delta G= -T\Delta S_\rm{universe}$ (at const. temp. and pressure) is wrong?

Comment: I'm saying that, for a reversible process at constant temperature and pressure, the non-PV work done by the universe is zero, and $\Delta G$ of the universe is zero.  But please understand that, the real applicability of the equation in Atkins is for a closed system (*of lesser extent* than the entire universe) experiencing a reversible change at constant temperature and pressure.  I've run out of ideas on how to explain this more clearly.  Maybe someone else can help out.  I need to go to bed now.

Comment: Good night ;) So, at reversible process, the non-expansion work of the universe is zero?

Comment: I think it is a very bad idea to think of this in terms of the universe.  The focus should be on a finite closed system.  If you include both the system and surroundings, then this combination can't do work on anything (either reversible or irreversible).  The work the system does on the surroundings is just the negative of the work that the surroundings does on the system, so the sum of the two (the net work) is zero.  Try to picture in your mind the universe doing work on anything, given that work only occurs at the boundary of a system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36178/discussion-between-user36790-and-chester-miller).

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm pretty much out of ideas on how to explain this.

Comment: @user36790 In the future, it's better to formulate some of these into new questions rather than having a back and forth in chat between just two people.

Comment: @Chester Miller : Have you visited the chat-room & read my comment?

Comment: At constant temperature and volume, \begin{align}W_T & \le (U_1- U_2)- T(S_1-S_2)\\ \implies W_T & \le (F_1 -F_2) \end{align} Now, if reversibility exists then $$W_T= F_1- F_2$$ though $dS_\textrm{universe} = 0$

Comment: Generally it is written that $$\mathrm dS_\textrm{surr}= \frac{-\mathrm dH_\textrm{sys}}{T}$$ but it is valid only when the non-expansion work is zero. Generally $$\mathrm dH = \underbrace{w'}_{\textrm{non-expansion work}} + \delta q$$

Comment: So, when one uses $\mathrm dH $ to denote heat transferred (or absorbed) in the surroundings, then he is definitely taking $w' = 0\,,$ isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The proper equation is
$$\mathrm dG=\mathrm dH-\mathrm d(TS)$$
Since $H=U+pV$, we rewrite the above equation as
$$\mathrm dG=\mathrm dU+(p\mathrm dV+V\mathrm dp)-T\mathrm dS-S\mathrm dT$$
Furthermore, we know from the first law that
$$\mathrm dU=\delta Q + \delta W$$
and
$$\Delta S=\int{\frac{\delta Q_\text{rev}}{T}}$$
which is equivalent to writing
$$T\mathrm dS=\delta Q_\text{rev}$$
so, putting it all together and remembering that temperature is constant, we have
$$\mathrm dG=T\mathrm dS+\delta W_\text{rev}-T\mathrm dS$$
Then,
$$\mathrm dG=\delta W_\text{rev}$$
where the pressure-volume work went to zero because, as you point out in one of your comments, all of this is only valid for zero expansion work.

I hope this kind of answers your question, but you seem to have a pretty good grasp on this already.

---

Also, it probably shouldn't be written that 
$$\mathrm dG=\mathrm dW_\text{rev}$$
because this seems to imply that integrating this expression will have you take an integral with respect to work, but this cannot be done because work is not a state function. You would figure this out, however, when trying to figure out what values of work to use as the boundaries in that integral.

Comment: $\delta Q\ne 0\,\,\textrm{but}\,\,=  T\mathrm dS$

Comment: For a reversible process the heat transfer does equal zero.

Comment: No, no; this does happen only for adiabatic process.

Comment: Ya you're right about that. I think there shouldn't be heat transfer in this case because I believe this is how Atkins gets to the result you're talking about.

Comment: @jheindel It is not correct to say that "for a reversible process, there must be no heat loss from the system."  What about an isothermal reversible process?

Comment: @jheindel Also, your expressions for dG are incorrect.  dG=dH-d(TS), which leads to dG=VdP-SdT

Comment: Oh I see where it's going wrong. I'll edit it later. And ya you're right. At the time I couldn't figured out what was thing wrong so I reasoned very poorly.